# Plot unsimilar data with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the different lines, but one of the observations is far more beyond the normal scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)

a = matrix(rnorm(50, 0, 1), ncol=5)
b = c(rnorm(5, 0, 2), rnorm(5,20,2))
dt = data.frame(a,b)
rownames(dt) = paste0('Day',1:10)
colnames(dt) = c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
mdt = melt(as.matrix(dt), varnames=c('Date', 'Model'))
head(mdt)
ggplot(mdt, aes(x=Date, y=value, group=Model, color=Model))+
  geom_line(size=1.2)
```

This is what I got:
[image]

As you can see, the large fluctuation of `F` enlarges my general `y` axis scale and makes the other five observations' trends unclear.

I tried to set the `ylim=(-5,5)`, then I lost the entire `F`:
[image]

I am not entirely sure how shall I plot all of them together, but I am thinking is it possible to scale the out of range part, like the following part, or you actually wouldn't recommend this?

[image]

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you've got both positive and negative y values, so normal transforms like log won't work. You could [build your own transform](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/trans_new.html), say `sign(y)*log(abs(y))`, but making them is a bit of a pain in my experience. A simpler option is to facet with `scales = 'free_y'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best option for you data, but you can divide each group by it's range to make it more like a ratio.

```
  library(data.table)   
  library(ggplot2)

  set.seed(99)

  dt <- data.table(value = c(rnorm(10, 0, 5), rnorm(20)),
                   cat = rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each = 10),
                   id = rep(1:10, 3))

  ggplot(dt, aes(id, value, color = cat)) +
    geom_line(size = 2)

  ggplot(dt[, ratio := value / diff(range(value)), cat], aes(id, ratio, color = cat)) +
    geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

[image]